# erlang slave:start/2 connection refused

Tags: erlang

The os is Mac os lion.
The longname connection between two nodes is ok, if the commands are `'erl -name aa'` and `'erl -name bb'`.

But if using slave:start/2, the connection confused error occurs as follows:

```
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)33> slave:start('yus-iMac.local',bb).
connect to address 192.168.64.1: Connection refused
Trying 192.168.213.1...
connect to address 192.168.213.1: Connection refused
Trying 192.168.0.101...
connect to address 192.168.0.101: Connection refused
Trying fe80::654:53ff:fe0e:b2ee%en1...
connect to address fe80::654:53ff:fe0e:b2ee%en1: Connection refused
Trying 192.168.64.1...
connect to address 192.168.64.1: Connection refused
Trying 192.168.213.1...
connect to address 192.168.213.1: Connection refused
Trying 192.168.0.101...
connect to address 192.168.0.101: Connection refused
Trying fe80::654:53ff:fe0e:b2ee%en1...
connect to address fe80::654:53ff:fe0e:b2ee%en1: Connection refused
Trying 192.168.64.1...
connect to address 192.168.64.1: Connection refused
Trying 192.168.213.1...
connect to address 192.168.213.1: Connection refused
Trying 192.168.0.101...
connect to address 192.168.0.101: Connection refused
Trying fe80::654:53ff:fe0e:b2ee%en1...
connect to address fe80::654:53ff:fe0e:b2ee%en1: Connection refused
Trying 192.168.64.1...
connect to address 192.168.64.1: Connection refused
Trying 192.168.213.1...
connect to address 192.168.213.1: Connection refused
Trying 192.168.0.101...
connect to address 192.168.0.101: Connection refused
Trying fe80::654:53ff:fe0e:b2ee%en1...
connect to address fe80::654:53ff:fe0e:b2ee%en1: Connection refused
Trying 192.168.64.1...
connect to address 192.168.64.1: Connection refused
Trying 192.168.213.1...
connect to address 192.168.213.1: Connection refused
Trying 192.168.0.101...
connect to address 192.168.0.101: Connection refused
Trying fe80::654:53ff:fe0e:b2ee%en1...
connect to address fe80::654:53ff:fe0e:b2ee%en1: Connection refused
Trying 192.168.64.1...
connect to address 192.168.64.1: Connection refused
Trying 192.168.213.1...
connect to address 192.168.213.1: Connection refused
Trying 192.168.0.101...
connect to address 192.168.0.101: Connection refused
Trying fe80::654:53ff:fe0e:b2ee%en1...
yus-imac.local: Connection refused
{error,timeout}
```

The longname test is as folows:

```
yus-iMac:~ yuchen$ erl -name cc
Erlang R15B (erts-5.9) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)
(cc@yus-iMac.local)1> 

yus-iMac:~ yuchen$ erl -name dd
Erlang R15B (erts-5.9) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)
(dd@yus-iMac.local)2> net_adm:ping('cc@yus-iMac.local').
pong
(dd@yus-iMac.local)3>
```

Comment: You state: "The longname connection between two nodes is ok". How did you try it?

Comment: I have added the long name testing in the previous post.

Answer (score 2):

By default, when you start nodes through the `slave` API an RSH connection is used. Reading from the [doc](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/slave.html):

> "A slave node started on the same host as the master inherits certain
>   environment values from the master, such as the current directory and
>   the environment variables. For what can be assumed about the
>   environment when a slave is started on another host, read the
>   documentation for the rsh program."

Maybe that's the problem. You should verify whether the RSH connection is fine on your host. An alternative to the rsh program can be specified on the command line when launching the 'erl' command:

```
erl -rsh ssh
```

Hope this might drive you to the right direction. I'm not running Lion, so I can't really tell.

Comment: I have tried this direction. It seems difficult for lion os. Its ssh doesn't contain ssh-askpass. Thank you very much.